# mysql utcdate string comparison codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

in codeigniter have a MySQL database with date column in this format

`Mon, 12 Sep 2017 13:54:04 GMT` .

i want to get records for last one year i.e period from 
`Mon, 12 Sep 2016 13:54:04 GMT`
til now.
 i am trying to form a where clause for it but cant figure out how to compare two utcdate strings.

i tried using
 `$this->db->where('DATE(created) >=',$_POST['duration']);` 
but it doesn't work. all values in created column are in above format.

Comment: What column data type are these dates held in?

Comment: they are in TEXT datatype

Comment: There is your problem. Dates and Times should **always** be held in DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP data type columns. You then show the user any format they want in the presentation layer

Comment: i understand that part. its an old project. and i am adding some features in it. so the dev who previously worked has stored js utcdatestrings all over and now if i change database, its a huge workload for me

Comment: You are going to have to use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function on these Strings to make them into proper dates

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. `STR_TO_DATE(substr("Mon, 14 Aug 2017 13:54:04 GMT",1,25), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")` this worked:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STR_TO_DATE(substr("Mon, 14 Aug 2017 13:54:04 GMT",1,25), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%S")`.
for anyone else searchingn for samething. RiggsFolly helped me to this answer.